# AsyncHttpClient box.com Access token not found

Tags: android, box-api, android-async-http

I was trying to upload a text file at box.com. I am using the Android Asynchronous Http Client on this. I prefer to use it because it is cleaner. Box.com file upload instructions here: http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-upload-a-file.

I tried and always get the access token was not found error. I prefer not to use the android box.com sdk.

```
File myFile = new File(path_to_file + "test.txt"));
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

params.put("filename", "test.txt");
params.put("parent_id", "0");

AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

client.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + "TOKEN");
client.post("https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content", params, new      AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
@Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            System.out.println(response);
        }
    });


Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {bearer=WWW-    Authenticate: Bearer realm="Service", error="invalid_request", error_description="The access token was not found."}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by removing the Content-MD5 header which I included(which I forgot to mention above about it). Somehow the value in the header is not setup right.